# Flutter Error: Could not set the project description for 'gradle' because the project description file (.project) is out of sync with the file system

Tags: flutter, firebase

I just created a brand new flutter project and used the CLI to create a firebase project. When I opened my project code in VS Code for the first time, I see the following issue when I click on the Android folder:

```
Cannot add nature org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleprojectnature to Eclipse project gradle.
Could not set the project description for 'gradle' because the project description file (.project) is out of sync with the file system.
```

It doesn't prevent the app from launching in an emulator, but it does show as an error with a red x in the "Problems" tab.

Any idea how to fix this?